# pylearn2をインストールするときのUnicodeDecodeErrorエラー

Tags: python

http://deeplearning.net/software/pylearn2/

↑こちらの方法に沿ってインストールするとき　python setup.py develop
以下のエラーが

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 39: ordinal not in range(128)

ソースの中に日本語もいないし、ディフォルトをasciiからutf8に変更しでも、解決ができません。
どうすればいいのか？

pythonの新人です！

```
(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2) C:\Users\lab>cd pylearn2

(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2) C:\Users\lab\pylearn2>python setup.py develop
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg\setuptool
s\dist.py:331: UserWarning: Normalizing '0.1dev' to '0.1.dev0'
running develop
running egg_info
writing requirements to pylearn2.egg-info\requires.txt
writing pylearn2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pylearn2.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pylearn2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'pylearn2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'pylearn2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Looking for python27.dll
Building import library (arch=AMD64): "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\libs\libpython27
.a" (from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\python27.dll)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 87, in <module>
    '': ['*.cu', '*.cuh', '*.h'],
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_comman
ds
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_comman
d
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg\s
etuptools\command\develop.py", line 34, in run
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg\s
etuptools\command\develop.py", line 119, in install_for_development
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_comman
d
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ex
t.py", line 185, in run
    _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 309,
in run
    force=self.force)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py"
, line 596, in new_compiler
    compiler = klass(None, dry_run, force)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompi
ler.py", line 93, in __init__
    build_import_library()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompi
ler.py", line 377, in build_import_library
    return _build_import_library_amd64()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompi
ler.py", line 399, in _build_import_library_amd64
    generate_def(dll_file, def_file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompi
ler.py", line 271, in generate_def
    if _START.match(dump[i].decode()):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 43: invalid
start byte
```

Comment: `python setup.py develop`を実行しているフォルダのパスに日本語が含まれていたりしませんか？

Comment: ユーザーフォルダーを使っています。でもパスの中にUsersを使ってます。anacondaはデフォルトにをユーザーフォルダー使っている感じですね。

Comment: ユーザー名はアルファベットのみでしょうか

Comment: ユーザーはアルファベットのみです。

Comment: なんとなくロケールの問題っぽいですが`chcp 65001`を実行してからsetupするとどうなりますか？

Comment: できました！！ありがとうございます．

Answer (score 1):

setup.py がCのコンパイラを要求しているのにそのコマンドがないと

> 'c:\hogehoge....\c-compiler-command'  は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、 操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ
>   ファイルとして認識されていません。

という応答が返ってきて、この最初の日本語 `は` の部分が UnicodeDecodeError を起こします。

エラーのスタックトレースを見る限り、それに類するような症状だろうと推測します。

C言語環境はちゃんと整えていますか?
C言語に関する知識はしっかりと持っていますか?

PythonのパッケージでC言語拡張が必要なパッケージの環境構築をWindowsでやろうとすると、Unix系のOSを使う時以上に、C言語に関する知識が求められますよ。
UnixならOSのパッケージを適切にインストールしておけば済むことでも、Windowsだと自分でやらないといけないですから。

Answer (score 0):

`python setup.py develop`を実行する前に`set PYTHONIOENCODING=cp932`または`set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`で環境変数を設定してみてください。

Comment: 設定しでも同じエラー出てくるですね。